# I've been trying to use logrotate utility and move the compressed logs to s3, however, it rotates only when done forcefully

Tags: amazon-s3, logrotate, s3cmd

I've configured it to run hourly, it rotates logs hourly but not sending it to s3, what could be the reason?

/var/log/newlog
{

```
rotate 5
hourly
missingok
notifempty
compress
dateext
    dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S
postrotate
    /usr/lib/newlog/new
endscript
```

/usr/lib/newlog/new is a script, using s3cmd to sync .gz files to s3

Answer (score 0):

From the above code it is seen that, there is no mention of S3 bucket to which the log files should be compressed.
Your script should add the following lines:

---

/var/log/newlog {

```
   postrotate
    /usr/lib/newlog/new > /dev/null 2>&1 || true

    BUCKET=logging-bucket
    INSTANCE_ID=`curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id | sed -e "s/i-//"`
    /usr/bin/s3cmd -m text/plain sync /var/log/messages-* s3://${BUCKET}/${INSTANCE_ID}/var/log/

endscript
```

}

---

where logging-bucket is name of the bucket in which the compressed files will be stored.
Also make sure the user has permissions to the S3.

Thanks